# How to use moment.Moment attribut directly in Angular?

Tags: angular, date, momentjs

My Angular model contain a Date. Is it possible use directly a moment.Moment Object? I deserialize a REST API with a date (ex: `2019-10-01T11:06:03`). If the model contains an attribute of type `Date` do not work. If the model contains an attribute of type `moment.Moment` **do not work**.

For now, I have the following code:

```
export class Foo {

    public startDate: Date;
}

moment(foo.startDate).locale('fr').format('dddd DD MMMM')
```

How to use directly a moment.Moment Object?

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
export class Foo {

    public startDate: moment.Moment;
}

foo.startDate.locale('fr').format('dddd DD MMMM')  <= This do not work (format is not a function)
```